# Java swing gui and lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl

A simple question: **Is it possible to view gui of java Swing library and lwjgl 3D scene in the same window without using any additional gui libraries? How?**

Comment: Can you please clarify: what exactly is a "java default gui"?

Comment: well java has a gui that you can use wthout any libraries. Am i calling it wrong?

Comment: gui - graphical user interface

Comment: Yeah, I think I know what "GUI" means. Are you referring to a Swing GUI or AWT GUI? Both are libraries that are part of core Java and can be used to create GUI's.

Comment: Java has built-in libraries to create GUIs- `Swing` and `AWT`

Comment: If the lwjgl 3D scene can be made into an image of some sort, say a jpg or png image, then either AWT or Swing can display it.

Comment: Or if it can be made into an array of ints that hold the RGBA bytes (for red, green, blue, and alpha composite), then this can be displayed as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you can write a full anwser about that.

Comment: I would, but I know nothing about the lwjgl libraries, and so I don't know if 3d images can be converted to the rgba ints.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels look at this http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setParent(java.awt.Canvas)

Comment: I don't see how one can get the image from the Display other than with a Robot object -- now that will work.

Comment: look at the setParent() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method Display.setParent(java.awt.Canvas) to put the LWJGL display on a canvas. You can then incorporate this canvas into your Swing GUI. Please note that there may be slight performance issues with said approach.