# Rendering javax.swing.JButton in a lwjgl window

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl

Is it possible to render a javax.swing.JButton and other swing elements in a lwjgl window (with openGL)? If not, what can you recomend for in game GUI in lwjgl?

*Note: i tried Nifty-GUI and TWL, but i dont like the XML part, and the documentation was poor...*

Comment: What happens when you try? What about `java.awt.Button`? Why not an adjacent panel or modeless dialog?

Comment: Actualy i hadint tried that, because i have no idea how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `javax.swing.JButton` to a `java.awt.Canvas` used for [`Display`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html) may be subject to rendering artifacts. Instead, try one of the following alternatives:

- Add the button to a `JPanel`, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). Put your `Display` in a `Canvas`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11358217/230513). Put both in a suitable layout, e.g.

  ```
  add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER;
  add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  ```
- Control your `Display` using components in a modeless dialog, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).