# LWJGL display and java swing

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl

I have created a JFrame with a JSplitPane in it, which contains a canvas in the left and a JPanel in the right. 
The canvas contains LWJGL display, and the JPanel has few JTextFields in it. The problem is that when I press a mouse button on the LWJGL display, I can't write text into JTextFields anymore. When I minimize the application and return it back, it works until I press on the display again.

**Why do i get this problem? How can i fix it?**

*Note: I can focus on the text fields, but i cant write anything. Maybe the LWJGL is somehow blocking Swings keyboard input?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a `java.awt.Canvas` to a `javax.swing.JSplitPane`, you're [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html). As an alternative, you might try one of the approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447916/230513).